# Error while exporting using node and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So, I have create some schema like following and exporting the model,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var specSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description:String
});

var qualSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description:String
});


var doctorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,

    // qualifications:[qualSchema],
    // specializations:[specSchema]
});

var Doctor = mongoose.model('Doctor',doctorSchema);
module.exports = Doctor/**please see here**/
```

This works fine.

However later i thought that I would like to export the schema also from this js file, so i changed the last line as follows:

```
module.exports = {Doctor,doctorSchema}
```

My code started failing,
then i realised that if I write

```
module.exports = {Doctor} /**i.e add curly braces to it**/
```

my code fails again.

This is how we export in node ? right? but this is failing my code.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: For some, code fails silently, for some it says "have no constructor for Doctor(model's name
)" @Rashomon

Comment: How are you importing the exported variables in the new case? Maybe you are using a default import for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export model and schema as follows:

First Option:

```
module.exports = Doctor
```

Import as

```
const Doctor = require('exportedSchemaFilePath')
```

Second Option:

```
module.exports = {Doctor,doctorSchema}
```

Import as

```
const {Doctor, DoctorSchema} = require('exportedSchemaFilePath')
```

As you are exporting as JSON object

Third option:

```
module.exports = {Doctor}
```

import as

```
const {Doctor} = require('exportedSchemaFilePath')
```

You just need to change require option as you change export methods

Comment: Yea, that works, second option it was, the import was incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How are you importing the schema? You should extract the schema name using the dot notation since you are exporting an object.

```
const Doctor = require('exportedSchemaPath').Doctor;
```

Comment: Yes kunal, the thing is even if I dont extract it or use it at any place, still writing the above syntax creates issue.

Comment: It should not give an error if the module is not being used anywhere. As per your comment above you mentioned that the error says "have no constructor for Doctor(model's name )". I believe it's because the code is unable to find the model constructor in the file. Can you provide more details about the error?